# Is it possible to submit form twice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the situation like updating values to db when form is submitted.Issue here is, Total is calculated only after form is submitted. so i have to update the calculated total again in DB. I need to submit again manually to update it. To achieve this we can use jquery here to form submitted second time with out click it again. Is there quick way to do this ?

Kindly advice ?

Comment: There is something else fundamentally wrong when you have to submit a form twice for it to work.

Comment: Actually once my form is submitted i am calling third party service to get result and then i calculate with my total and store my total in hidden text box.when i update it again,hidden value will store in DB.Here I dont want to click submit again.

Comment: Why are you storing the total in a hidden?  Why can't you call the DB save method immediately after you calculate the total?

Comment: Then your form should be submitted only once, your data is taken care of on the server which integrates with the 3rd party service and then, when that service returns the result, the data should be saved into your DB. Another approach would be to update your DB twice, once with the form data that is not "total" value and then, when the service returns - update the DB with the "total" value. This should be done in the same transactional space, of course.

Answer (score 3):

You can use ajax to submit form twice, see following code:

```
function submit() {
  var form = $('#your-form');
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: form.attr('action'),
    data: form.serialize(),
    success: function(data) {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: form.attr('action'),
        data: form.serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
        }
      });
    }
  });
}
```