# Javascript How to auto submit

Tags: javascript

I am writing a script to make a page auto submit twice. The script should first press the first submit button, then have a small delay and press the second. Both are on the same document.

What I am doing is: get the document, then use document.GetElementByID('id_button').click(), and have timeOut for a delay to the second click. Thing is, the first button works fine, but the second won't work. I don't know why. Is my approach correct?

Comment: Once the first submit finishes, the original page is gone and no longer relevant.  You will need to involve AJAX in your solution if you want to simultaneously post data to multiple servers.

Comment: It's only one server, it just has a submit and a confirm buttons.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7991152/1048572

Answer (score 0):

Have the action on the form reflect the state.

```
/Page.HTML

/Page.HTML? washere=true 

/Page.HTML? washereagain=true
```

That can be identified by your script

Comment: Wait, what do you mean? Could you explain it further please?

Comment: Sure....check for URL parameters, if none submit.if 'washere=true', submit again.if washereagain= true' you have submitted twice.....very low level, involves page reload, but works....

Comment: I see what you mean... But I don't think it will work with the site I am trying to use. It basically is just a "stage" where new screens are loaded as needed, with the submit on one screen and submit on a different one. I suppose that even if there was an error and I was taken to the error page I would still get the same error...

Answer (score 0):

> What I am doing is: get the document, then use document.GetElementByID('id_button').click(),

Not all browsers support the *click* method for submit buttons, so your strategy will fail for a good number of browsers in use.

You can submit the form by calling its *submit* method. If you want to auto-submit it a certain number of times (which seems a pointless exercise, but that's your choice), set a cookie each time you submit the form and check it when the page loads to see how many times it's been submitted.